# using bokeh to create a bar graph

Tags: python, bokeh

there is an example on the bokeh website:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_nested.html

but it does not work on my Jupiter notebook.

I have the following data frame:

```
                precision   recall  f1
Random Forest   0.493759    1.0     0.661096
XGBoost         0.493759    1.0     0.661096
```

I want to build a graph that compares the two models on these 3 metrics. 
But to start, I just wanted to compare one metric. this is my non-working code:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

data = pd.DataFrame({'precision':[percision_rf,percision_xgb],'recall':[recall_rf,recall_xgb],'f1':[f1_rf,f1_xgb]})
data.rename({0:'Random Forest',1:'XGBoost'}, inplace=True)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure()

p.vbar(x='Random Forest', top=0.9, width=0.9, source=source)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

There is an example of a simple bar graph on the bokeh website, but it is not using a ColumnDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `DataFrame` to a `ColumnDataSource`, Bokeh makes CDS columns out of the columns of the DataFrame. *Those* are what you can refer to in the glyph methods, and then the glyph will draw glyphs for *all* values of that column. For example, in the example above, you could do

```
# plot bars for every precision value along the x axis
p.vbar(x='precision', top=0.9, width=0.9, source=source)
```

All Bokeh glyphs are inherently "vectorized" in this way.

In the above code, `x='Random Forest'` is not meaningful to pass to `vbar`, because there is no column in the `DataFrame` (and hence no column in the CDS) called "Random Forest".